# closest() of this.element not works properly

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML like this.: And when I click on tag `<a>` I need to get closest parent node with selector `".container"`
The script is below, but it works only for the first one column (with the first one specify selector) How to bring the code works properly like with `this` parameter or something else?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sub-container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sub-container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sub-container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script

```
<script>    

    (() =>{
        const a = document.querySelectorAll('a');

        for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            a[i].setAttribute('onclick', `handleClick('${a[i].getAttribute('data-color')}', '${a[i].nodeName}')`);
    }
        handleClick = (color, selector) => {
        document.querySelector(selector).closest('.container').style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    })()

</script>
```

Comment: There is no need to do any of what you are doing.

Comment: Show me please the best way to works this properly

Comment: You have an IIFE to prevent polluting global namespace but then want to use primitive `onclick` which requires global namespaced function. Use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: Sure! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add event handlers with `.addEventListener()`, and the handlers should be functions, not strings:

```
(() => {
  const a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.closest(".container").style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute("data-color");
    });
  }
})();
```

You could also do it with a delegation setup, such that you handle "clicks" at the document level and dispatch to the color changer when the event target matches `".container a"` (or whatever works).

Comment: Thank you! And what if I set a new one link to make an animation. Is it shoul be looks like this: `document.querySelector('a[class=animate]).addEventListener('click', function() {setInterval(function(){a[i].click()}, 2000)}` ?

Comment: @31113 yes, you can do that, though you may want to save the interval timer identity (the return value from `setInterval()`) so you can stop the timer later.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy!

Answer (score 2):

You are over complicating it by passing in colors to the event handler. You are using a data attribute so just read it when you click on the element.

```js
(() => {
  
  const handleClick = evt => {
    // stop the click
    evt.preventDefault()
    // get the color
    const color = evt.target.dataset.color
    // reference the container element
    const wrapper = evt.target.closest('.container')
    // clean up classes
    wrapper.classList.remove('red', 'green', 'blue')
    //set class for what was clicked
    wrapper.classList.add(color)
  }
  
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  anchors.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', handleClick))

})()
```

```css
a:after {
  content: attr(data-color)
}

div.red {
  background-color: red
}

div.green {
  background-color: green
}

div.blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can even avoid the loop over the anchors and use event delegation

```js
(() => {
  
  const handleClick = evt => {
    // look to see if what we click has the data attribute
    const color = evt.target.dataset.color
    // if we do not have the color, than just ignore the click
    if(!color) return

    // stop the click
    evt.preventDefault()
    // reference the container element
    const container = evt.target.closest('.container')
    // clean up classes
    container.classList.remove('red', 'green', 'blue')
    //set class for what was clicked
    container.classList.add(color)
  }
  
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
  wrapper.addEventListener('click', handleClick)

})()
```

```css
a:after {
  content: attr(data-color)
}

div.red {
  background-color: red
}

div.green {
  background-color: green
}

div.blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="red" class="red"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="green" class="green"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-color="blue" class="blue"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```